# Does it matter where you put the brackets in the main method?

Tags: java, formatting, format

I am currently starting to learn Java and I have been looking at some code and have seen the brackets in two different places.

These are the two ways I have seen it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

public static void main(String args[]) {
```

Is one of these ways correct formatting or is it simply whichever the programmer prefers?

Comment: It's a matter of preference. Both are correct.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Technically, it is a matter of your preference. When defining arrays, both are legal.

However, there is an overwhelming tendency and standard to put the brackets after the reference type, as in `String[] args`. Some code inspection tools even consider the other use of brackets as a bad convention or "code smell".

Answer (score 3):

From the [Google Java style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html#s4.8.3.2-array-declarations):

> The square brackets form a part of the type, not the variable: `String[]` args, not `String args[]`.

However, both are legal.

Answer (score 1):

From the [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.1):

> The [] may appear as part of the type at the beginning of the
>   declaration, or as part of the declarator for a particular variable,
>   or both.

It makes no difference. The two forms exist so as not to scare off C/C++ programmers from learning Java.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of taste, you can write `String[] args` or `String args[]`. However, please be consistent, i.e. choose one of them and use this method for every array declaration as it improves readability.

I personally always write `String[] args` as in my opinion, you should see by the type that it is an array. Also, it is more consistent with `String[] array = new String[count]`, since the brackets go with the type on the right hand side.